# Javascript in iAd Producer

Tags: javascript, ios, iad

I'm really struggling to find documentation for Javascript in iAd producer.  If Anyone has a link it would be much appreciated.

I need to register click events on images and either displace a layer that is not visible, import an asset from the library or move an item into the stage from off screen.  Has anyone got any code examples I could use for this?

I also need to detect the orientation of the device so I can move in an assest from off the stage.

Comment: [As of December 31, 2016, the iAd App Network is no longer available.](https://developer.apple.com/support/iad/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm learning it myself and hoping to do things similar to what it sounds like you are doing.  But have you been using this as a resource?

https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/navigation/index.html

I see there's information about the device orientation in a couple of places that I see but I'm not 100% sure this is exactly what you are looking for:

https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/#documentation/iAdJS/Reference/iAd.DeviceClassRef/iAd/iAd.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012111

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/deviceorientationevent#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010526

Comment: I was told simply to create a second banner and add one in landscape, one in portrait and the relevant one should be served up by someone from apple.  The above links dont work btw.  The documentation seem fairly poor for iAd

Comment: You might need a developer account to access the information at the links.  The links work fine for me but I do need to log in using my AppleID.  In general, Apple's documentation is fairly thorough but I find it very difficult to find what I need.

Comment: As of December 31, 2016, the iAd App Network is no longer available.